# Dynamic Forms in SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

in my application the user is requested to enter data in a form-like editor. 
A form contains a couple of items of different data types (strings, dates, 
numbers).
I am looking into Eclipse forms to build this editor, composing the form of 
different input elements, one for each data type.
Since the underlying model is not static (items may be added/removed 
depending on user selection),
the form view must be dynamically rebuild on model changes. Using SWT I 
could have removed all components from the forms
and added the updated components again. How can this be done in SWT / 
Eclipse Forms API ? I tried to dispose() the form widgets and create
new ones, but the newly created widgets won't appear. 
Since I am new to SWT 
this is probably not the way things are meant to be done.
Any ideas or sample code would help...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `dispose()` and creation of new form elements, try to call `parent.layout()` in order to position your new widgets.